# std::byte's to_integer<uint8_t> interprets to char instead of integer

Tags: c++, c++17

I was playing around with C++17 `std::byte`, and I came across some weird behaviour.
I don't know if it is intended or not, or if I am doing something wrong.

```cpp
std::byte test_byte{80};
std::cout << "Test: " << std::to_integer<uint8_t>(test_byte) << " vs " << std::to_integer<uint16_t>(test_byte) << "\n";
```

This will print out:

```
Test: P vs 80
```

I then looked up the ASCII table and found that uppercase P's numerical value is 80.

My question is if this is the intended or if it's a bug, or maybe even OS/Compiler specific?

Running Windows 10 and compiling with VS Build Tools.

Comment: How do you expect overloaded operator= differ between `unsigned char` and `uint8_t`?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie - Well, compilers are free to provide an 8 bit unsigned integral type that is not `unsigned char` for the purposes of the `uint8_t`. It doesn't *have* to be aliasing `unsigned char`. Nowadays there is too much code assuming it does, so it will likely never happen. But there is no inherent reason.

Comment: On systems with `uint8_t` it's typically an alias of `unsigned char`, and *all* `char` types are written as characters with the `<<` operator. You need to cast to any other integer type (e.g. plain `unsigned int`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is if this is the intended

Sort of.

> if it's a bug

No. It's just a slight inconvenience in the API.

> or maybe even OS/Compiler specific?

No.

This has nothing to do with `std::to_integer`. The issue is that the integer type that is 8 bits wide on your system happens to be (`unsigned`) `char`. And this integer type happens to also be a character type.

And integers that are characters are treated differently from integers that aren't character types by character streams. Specifically, the behaviour is to print the character encoded by that integer, rather than textual representation of the value.

The solution is to convert the `uint8_t` into a wider integer type such as `unsigned int` before inserting it into a character stream.

Comment: Curious fact, that in case of `int8_t` things may go hairy because signed version of those types are guaranteed to be complement of 2 (though code that uses them is implementation-depended, `intX_t` may be absent as not supported type). In a way C++ contradicts java\python\C# dogmatists who say that  only signed integers are portable and safe to use (in reality it is safe to use only on same platform, and signed overflows still handled differently by some languages.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie 2's complement guarantee is extended to all integer types in C++20. So, soon you won't have (recent version) of C++ at all on those exotic systems. `uint8_t` is also not guaranteed to exist, and probably doesn't on systems with byte wider than 8 bits (which I think may be more common than non-2's-complement).

Comment: that sounds like a mistake, or rather, mis-evaluation of importance. I may agree with guaranteed emulation of 2s compliment (conversion is rather simple but it isn't free). some of those "exotic" systems are actually very commonand more numerous that PCs, like multiple RSP systems in SDR or radars, comm equipment,  and some of those are essential (aka hundreds to millions lives hang on them because they control planes, radars, ships..) and use of a version of compliment of 1 format there is meaningful. Most of those don't care about float operations, all math done in integers.

Comment: What useful could be done, are ways to detect if compliment of 2s is "native format".

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Can you name the CPU / micro controllers used on such systems? I'd like to learn more. Do any of those systems have a C++ compiler? If yes, do any of those support C++17? If not, I doubt the future standard matters to them. Same proposal was made to C standard as well, but apparently failed to gain consensus in WG14 meeting (14 approved, 0 reject, 3 abstain).

Answer (score 1):

Compare these two lines of code:

```
unsigned char c = 80;

std::cout << c << '\n';
std::cout << +c << '\n';
```

This should help you to understand what is going on!

In the first case, it will print the `ASCII` character or even possibly the `UNICODE` character of that value depending on the architect and platform (Hardware Manufacturer: Intel, AMD, etc, and Windows, Mac, Linux, etc.) and the type of `stream_buf` that is being used... It may not even print anything and cause your internal computer's buzzer to beep depending on the value...

In the second case, it will print the actual value `80` to the console.

What is happening here is that the `unsigned char` is interpreted by the `std::basic_streambuf` class different than a conventional `integral` `signed` or `unsigned` type because it is of a `char` type. You may or may not see this same effect with a `signed char` I'm not 100% sure on that, but I am 100% sure of the `unsigned char` type.

The reason the value `80` is printed in the second case is due to the `unary` `operator+()` being prefixed to the `unsigned char` type. This causes integer promotion.

This characteristic or side-effect will carry out for any and all types that are either `typedef` or `aliased` from `unsigned char`.

In your case, you are seeing `P` being printed because you are casting or converting to the `unsigned char` type since `uint8_t` is an `unsigned char`!